# ROS running on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: ros, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to both ROS and Raspberry PI and need some good advice.

The software I want to run, has originally been written for the Raspberry PI 2.

Do you know if I will be able to run some ROS software written for RPi2 directly on the RPi3?

Specifically, I'm talking about http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/BlueROV.

Thanks and regards,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229860/ros-running-on-raspberry-pi-3/) by [balduros](https://answers.ros.org/users/26338/balduros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't received my RPi 3 yet but as I see from documentation, there is nothing that should break backwards compatibility.

The only thing about it is in excessive heat generation: try to benefit from infinite heatsink around your underwater vehicle :)

---

Originally posted by [NetBUG](https://answers.ros.org/users/26372/netbug/) with karma: 26 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lightbulb](https://answers.ros.org/users/26374/lightbulb/) on 2016-03-23**:
Hello, I plan to use RPi 3 for better performance in my project, but the problem I think is that we can use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in RPi2 which provides easy way to install ROS. Installing ROS in Rasbian is so difficult. Can we still use same Ubuntu in RPi 3? I am not sure.

**Comment by [NetBUG](https://answers.ros.org/users/26372/netbug/) on 2016-03-23**:\

1. Yes, you can choose between Ubuntu MATE (https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) and original 32-bit Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi
   64-bit for ARM has not become stable yet.
2. ROS on Debian is not that hard to implement :)

**Comment by [lightbulb](https://answers.ros.org/users/26374/lightbulb/) on 2016-03-23**:
Thank you, but I still have two questions. First, I use indigo, but it only support OS up to 14.04. But most ubuntu on pi3 are higher than 14.04. Maybe jade can be installed in them, but some packages are still flaw in jade. Second, I don't know if packages are well supported in Debian?

**Comment by [lightbulb](https://answers.ros.org/users/26374/lightbulb/) on 2016-03-23**:
I can just use apt-get to install them or I have to compile them by myself?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS Jade on RPi2 (Ubuntu 14.04) and ROS Kinetic on RPi3 (Ubuntu Mate 16.04) without any problems.

Note that by default hardware serial on RPi3 is connected to bluetooth. I didn't figure out how to break it out yet. Other than that all works great. Tested with Hokuyo laser scanner, usb_cam, etc. The heat is a bit of an issue, but at 50% CPU utilisation RPi2 is running at ~60C without problems.

Also, note that latest Ubuntu 16.04 for RPi3 is not stable yet (tested couple weeks back), thus using Ubuntu Mate.

---

Originally posted by [Marcin Bogdanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/26406/marcin-bogdanski/) with karma: 231 on 2016-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2